# Syncfusion JS OLAP

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, olap, syncfusion

Hi I am new with Syncfusion products, I work on Syncfusion JS on ASP.NET MVC on On https://help.syncfusion.com/js/pivotclient/olap-getting-started trying to Create a simple application with pivot client and OLAP data source (server mode), I already have all References they told later versions but it keep telling me that errors .. ANY HELP PLS!

> PivotGrid' does not contain a definition for 'GetJsonData' and no extension method 'GetJsonData and deserializedReports. The type or
>   namespace name 'Utils' does not exist in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contacting Syncfusion support.

We have analyzed your query, and we suspect that the reported problem occurs due to improper assembly references. (The assembly version needs to be same for all the Syncfusion DLL’s which are referred in the sample for.eg(.Net framework with Syncfusion build version-16.3450.0.29)).  Meanwhile, we have prepared a sample based on Getting Started UG content. Please find the sample link below.

Sample Link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/221489/ze/PIVOTC~1829580252

Regards,
Scintilla A